# Show badge when value is exists Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-8

I have 2 tables: **standarts** and **questions** where question's `standart_id` is the same as standart's `id`.

I want to show the status whether it's filled or empty with badge when the current data is equal to standart's `id`. How to accomplish that?

I've tried my best to find some reference but didn't find the one that I want.

Here's my blade:

```
    @foreach($standarts as $v)
        <tr>
            <td>Standart {{$v->id}}</td>
            <td class="text-capitalize">{{$v->name}}</td>
            <td>{{$v->year}}</td>
            <td class="text-capitalize">{{$v->type}}</td>
            @if($check == null)
                <td>
                    <span class="badge bg-danger tips"
                          data-bs-toggle="popover" title="Empty">
                        Empty
                    </span>
                </td>
            @else()
                <td>
                    <span type="button" class="badge bg-danger tips"
                          data-bs-toggle="popover" title="Filled">
                        Filled
                    </span>
                </td>
            @endif
        </tr>
    @endforeach
```

Model:

```
    public function index(Question $question)
    {
        $standarts = DB::table('standarts')
            ->select(DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(created_at,"%Y") as year, id, user_id, type, name'))
            ->get();

        $check = Question::where('standart_id', '=', Standart::get('id'))->first();

        return view('admin.dashboard', compact('standarts', 'check'));
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "filled or empty"?

Comment: the span badge, i have "filled span badge" and "empty span badge"

Comment: Yes, but how are these two terms defined in your case? How to determine that?

Comment: when the "standart_id" inside questions table equal to "id" inside standarts table

Comment: because inside standart have many questions

Comment: So in other words: If there's a match (one or more questions are linked to the standard), right?

Comment: yes thats right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use eloquent relationships:

```php
class Standart extends Model
{
    public function questions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Question::class);
    }
}
```

Controller:

```php
public function index(Question $question)
    {
        $standarts = Standart::with(['questions'])->get();

        return view('admin.dashboard', compact('standarts'));
    }
```

Blade view:

```
    @foreach($standarts as $v)
        <tr>
            <td>Standart {{$v->id}}</td>
            <td class="text-capitalize">{{$v->name}}</td>
            <td>{{$v->year}}</td>
            <td class="text-capitalize">{{$v->type}}</td>
            @if(!$v->questions->count())
                <td>
                    <span class="badge bg-danger tips"
                          data-bs-toggle="popover" title="Empty">
                        Empty
                    </span>
                </td>
            @else()
                <td>
                    <span type="button" class="badge bg-danger tips"
                          data-bs-toggle="popover" title="Filled">
                        Filled
                    </span>
                </td>
            @endif
        </tr>
    @endforeach
```

Comment: i got Undefined variable: standart

Comment: now i got `Undefined property: stdClass::$questions`